How to generate a normally distributed (gaussian) list on Power Query with Python
This is a self-answered question. I am trying to anonymize data in Power Query to include in my portfolio. I wanted a random number with a normal or gaussian distribution to be able to multiply by the real price of an item, that way the original data gets anonymized. The values distribution and functionality of the original dataset remains.
The original dataset includes a list of prices that I needed to alter slightly in order to anonymize. I was expecting to be able to complete it using only M but there is no "random normal" function as there is  in NumPy. I figured implementing a python column would be a good solution.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

First, load your original dataset that you are trying to anonymize into power query.
You'll need to set the privacy levels to ignore for your current file (I could not get it to work with data source settings and setting it to public as some forums suggested).
Turning off privacy in file options
Go to edit query for your table and click on Transform on the ribbon and then on 'Run Python Script'
Ribbon option to transform a column with Python. It doesn't only transform, you can add columns too, in the Python Script
All the data in your table will be included in a variable called 'dataset', the first line in the code is generated automatically by Power Query when you click on Python, the rest you can copy and paste to get the same result.
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
ds=dataset
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()
numbers = rng.normal(size=len(dataset))
ds['randG']=numbers
dataset = ds

You'll need to click on expand in the column to be able to see the data.
Expanded data with random value
This code will generate a new column in your table that is called randG with a normall distributed random number. You can then use that in a math function to alter the original amount slightly. In my case I will use it to drift a price above or below 20% of the original amount.
References
https://realpython.com/numpy-random-normal/
https://realpython.com/power-bi-python/
How to make a reproducible data sample in PowerBI using Python?
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Formula-Firewall-Query-references-other-queries-so-it-may-not/m-p/18619
